# Exam day or exam's day?

Tags: possessives, attributive-nouns, saxon-genitive, greengrocers-apostrophe

What one's correct?

> - I will see you on the **exam day**
> - I will see you on the **exam's day**
> - Today is the **exam day**
> - Today is the **exam's day**

And why?

Comment: @tchrist, why this question was closed? This is English-related question!

Answer (score 1):

Although the sentence might be phrased as "I will see you on the day of the exam," that doesn't mean that it can be rearranged with the so-called "Saxon genitive," "exam's day". In "day of *x*", *x* **describes** what happens on the day: *day of the exam, Day of Judgement,* and so on. The day doesn't belong to the exam, or judgement.

So when moving the describing noun to before the main noun (moving *exam* to before *day*), *exam* is a **noun used as an adjective** to describe the *day* (an "attributive noun"). Such nouns are not inflected for case or gender because adjectives are not inflected. Thus it should be left alone and "on the exam day" is right.

That said, "the day of the exam" is probably more idiomatic.

Comment: Just realised I meant to write **not inflected for case or number**  but the statement as written is not wrong. Adjectives are not inflected.

Comment: This is one instance where a plural attributive noun may also be used if appropriate: _exams day_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth **Possibly** but I'd be inclined to disagree in general. *On the day of the exams* would be **far** more likely than *on the exams day*.

Comment: I'd agree that "the day of the exam" is more usual, but OP asks about correct structures. There is nothing remotely incorrect about this statement: 'Exams day is Tuesday, Jan. 28.' (internet) Doubtless modelled on 'Sports Day' / 'Founder's Day' / 'Speech Day' ...