# apostrophe rules in academic writing

Tags: apostrophe

I've been reading papers from nucleate boiling mechanics and related areas, and I keep being puzzled by the usage of apostrophes. For example, we talk about bubbles:

*Numerical simulations of the bubble dynamics in viscoelastic media
showed varying degrees of success in accurately predicting the observations.*

Here we see *bubble dynamics* with no apostrophe. Then on the next page:

*Visualization of the multiflash imaging technique with
timing diagrams of the variable flash sequences used during each
phase of the bubble’s evolution with example images.*

Here we have *bubble's evolution*, apsotrophe present.  Or, another example:

*The assumption of material homogeneity in the model is
likely also not valid for agarose gels, particularly in the early
parts of a bubble’s lifetime.*

So is it equally correct to say the bubble's size and the bubble size, the heater's tempetature and the heater temperature, etc.?

Please help me sort it out. Many thanks to all who had enough patience to read all this.

Comment: The examples you've given all seen like normal and correct uses of an apostrophe (or no apostrophe).

Comment: Do you mean my sentence where I say  "So is it equally correct to say the bubble's size and the bubble size, the heater's tempetature and the heater temperature, etc." The bubble's size = the bubble size? the heater's temperature=the heater temperature? Thanks.

Comment: See [Should possessive 's be used when there is no possession in the strict sense?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288877/should-possessive-s-be-used-when-there-is-no-possession-in-the-strict-this-is/288899#288899), [Is it correct to say 'I write children books' – not possessive-case?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92362/is-it-correct-to-say-i-write-children-books-not-possessive-case/92364#92364), ['exam day' or 'exam's day'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/171093/exam-day-or-exams-day/171099#171099),...

Comment: [Why do we say 'a hotel room' and not 'a hotel's room'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159545/why-do-we-say-a-hotel-room-and-not-a-hotels-room/159560#159560)

Answer (score 4):

You're seeing a mix of noun adjuncts, where the word "bubble" is used to modify another word, and possessives, where is said to belong to a bubble.

*Bubble dynamics* is a discipline within fluid mechanics. To name the field, we need to have a general, described term like this. "A bubble's dynamics" would be talking about the motion of a particular bubble (and would not match with the actual way we use the term 'dynamics' within engineering science). You will seldom see possessives used to describe a topic, abstractly.

The possessive is used in "each phase of the bubble's evolution" to refer to the phases belonging to a particular bubble. Thus, the bubble in question has an evolution. Though sometimes this could refer to a characteristic bubble rather than a concrete example of a bubble, the possessive would not be used to name the topic examining bubbles evolving: that topic would be bubble evolution.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! That makes things a lot clearer to me now. But then again, all over the papers that I read I can see "the heater size", "the heater surface temperature" or "the superheated layer thickness etc., and it's very rarely that I come across "the heater's something" (with apostrophe). I'd be much obliged to get some comments on that. Thanks!!!

Comment: I keep thinking about this, and maybe the answer is: if the object cannot be used in something abstract like "bubble evolution as in  examining bubbles evolving", then it's ok not to use the apostrophe? There is no discipline or abstract topic that can be titled "the heater temperature", or the "layer thickness", as a matter of fact.

Comment: When I noted the things that the possessive form could not do, I was not establishing a boundary for what noun adjunct phrases can do. "Bubble dynamics" is valid by not "bubble's dynamic", while "bubble size" and "bubble's size" are both coherent thoughts, and both probably occur in the literature to describe the size of bubbles.

Comment: There is some subtle differences I can perceive, but not describe well, that might distinguish between noun adjunct phrases and the possessive form when both are coherent. Maybe it will help to say that when we use noun adjuncts, we are making nouns into modifiers, like adjectives. Where "a bubble's size" means "the size of a bubble" and "the bubble's size" means "the size of the bubble", "bubble size" means " *a(* bubble *)* size", where *a: {* nouns *} → {*  adjectives *}* . Can you grok the difference between a train station and a train's station?

Comment: Something to think about. Thank you!

Comment: @Elena There are different ways to express things in English. English gives ypu options. There is not necessarily a difference between all ways of different expression. Go with the flow. You can say *page numbers* and *pages' numbers* and refer to the same thing, albeit with a different approach (i.e,, grammatical construct) to express your meaning.